# How to define Emacs major mode over #!

Tags: python, emacs24, major-mode

I have defined a python mode I would like to use for all .py files. Including:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.py\\'" . my-python-mode))
```

correctly uses my mode in all files ending with .py unless that file begins with a

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

which several files I'm working with do. How can I make my-python-mode take preference to the python mode emacs is defaulting to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the emacs manual, you need to also update interpreter-mode-alist

It has the entry

```
("python" . python-mode)
```

Do the add-to -list here as well

> Second, if there is no file variable specifying a major mode, Emacs
>   checks whether the file's contents begin with ‘#!’. If so, that
>   indicates that the file can serve as an executable shell command,
>   which works by running an interpreter named on the file's first line
>   (the rest of the file is used as input to the interpreter). Therefore,
>   Emacs tries to use the interpreter name to choose a mode. For
>   instance, a file that begins with ‘#!/usr/bin/perl’ is opened in Perl
>   mode. The variable interpreter-mode-alist specifies the correspondence
>   between interpreter program names and major modes.